# 'MyGrid' object has no attribute 'pressed'

Tags: python, kivy

So i started python recently wanting to make some apps using kivy well i was following a tutorial and this was the code i tried looking at the tutorial again but i couldnt find anything so i could use some help. I also tried copy and pasting just so i am sure i didn't miss type anything.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="First Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Last Name: "))
        self.lastName = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press= self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

def pressed(self, instance):
    print("Pressed")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Is the indentation exactly the same in the question as in your code? If that's the case, I think the error is because the method `pressed` is not indented, and thus not part of `MyGrid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with your indentation. Your `pressed` is now out of `MyGrid` class. Probably you want it be method in that class. Like this:

```
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="First Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Last Name: "))
        self.lastName = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press= self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    #This is now indented under MyGrid class
    def pressed(self, instance):
        print("Pressed")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
```

Comment: Oh, I totally missed Hampus Larsson's comment. He had the same answer there without code example.